# Is there a console code formatter for Avro IDL?

Tags: avro, formatter, avro-tools

I wondered if there is a console formatter for "Avro IDL" files. Something like scalafmt.
In the official docs I [saw](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.11.1/idl-language/#ide-support) there is supporting of IDEs but we use difference IDEs and this case is not helping us.

it there a console formatter or some config for existing one for Avro IDL files?